# Requesting cover images by aspect ratio in facebook native ads

Tags: android, facebook-audience-network, native-ads

I am implementing facebook native ads in my android app using the facebook audience nework sdk. The thumbnails in app are of size 16:9 ratio. So in order to make the ads truly native I wanted that the cover image that I get from facebook is also of the similar dimension. Looking at the sdk documentation I couldn't find a way to request images by dimension.

So is it possible to request images by specific dimensions?